# Is there any extension in the market able to have 2 smtp service in the setting?

Tags: magento2, smtp, send-mail

Is there any extension in the market able to have 2 smtp service in the setting? when the primary smtp service fail, use secondary to send out email. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

There is no any module available using 2 smtp service. you have to do customization if you want to use 2 smtp

Like

Install Magesplaza_SMTP module and check if email is not delivered with primary smtp then call Magesplaza_SMTP send mail code.